# both led lights don't turn on

Tags: led

I just replaced a switch with an led compatible switch (lutron). It switches on two led lights. Currently i have one philips led bulb and one cree led bulb on the switch. I also figured out that the cree 65W bulb is not compatible with teh siwtch.

Now when i turn on the led switch, only one light stays on. If i take off any of the led light - the other one stays on. If i take off the philips, cree stays on and if i take off the cree then philips stays on.

Is it a problem of compatibility or i have not connected the switch properly? I think if i would not have connected it properly then one of the bulbs would never have turned on.

Should i put both bulbs to be cree or should i replace everything with the switch compatible led bulbs ?

Comment: Did both LED's work with the old switch? If so, then you have something wired wrong somewhere, or the new switch is not truly compatible, or you are trying to use a dimmer on non-dimmable lights.

Comment: No the cree led is the new one. So i havent really tried it with the old led switch

Comment: When you say "switch" do you actually mean dimmer, lighted switch, smart switch etc.?

Comment: both of them (old and new) were dimmer switches

Comment: Are both bulbs labeled "dimmable"? Some LEDs are not, even with LED compatible dimmers.

Comment: Dimmers aren't switches, so it would be clearer if you said "dimmer" when you mean that.  It's something we need to know.